# Is it possible to setup flutter on Visual Studio 2017 IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, dart, flutter

Is it possible to install flutter on VS 2017 IDE? (not Visual Studio Code) I can't seem to find any answer to this, and I really prefer working in VS 2017.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need IDE consider using Intellij Idea or Android Studio, both have Dart/Flutter support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not supported yet. You can use VisualStudio as an editor and you'll be able to run the flutter commands in the console to run the app. But you'll lose the debugging and intellisense.

Comment: well, that's unfortunate. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It's now 2022, with VS 2022.  Any update on this?  Any possibility to use Visual Studio 2022 with Dart?  I much prefer VS over VS Code.